# Android window is not giving me full screen

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have an issue, where I am adding an three ImageViews to an activity, one is a header, another a footer and the third sits in between within a ScrollView. I am using version android_2.1_r1 and I have noticed a very strange issue, can't figure out whats going on, although I can tell why its happening.

Seems that if I get the DecorView and ask for the visible rectangle, it is x=0 y=38 as the top of the screen? Why does it do this. If I change the size of the image at the top to be larger than 40 it goes away?

Just incase anyone was thinking of it, its not the below. I have this set.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

See attached screenshot. The red bar should be flush with the top. But for some reason the DecorView decides there is an inset at the top?????? Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

So I have found the issue, it is **ScrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode**, see my code below. When the commented out line is uncommented it causes the issue. But only if the top image view is smaller than 20 in height. Can someone shed some light????? I have tried.

- RelativeLayout
- AbsoluteLayout
- LinearLayout

**UPDATE 2**

Stranger still, when I rotate, then rotate back, its fixed!!! The x=0, y=38 inset is gone???? And the black line at the top of my screen goes???

**UPDATE 3**

This issue goes away when I show the soft key pad, its as if it resets something. I can also fix it with an OnGlobalLayoutListener by using reflection to set the root view insets to 0.

```
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
      AndroidActivity activity = screen.getActivity();
      Window window = activity.getWindow();
      View view = window.getDecorView();  

      view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(currentlyVisibleRect);

      if(currentlyVisibleRect.top > 0) {
         // Below code will not work....but you get the idea
         Field field1 = view.getClass().getDeclaredField("mAttachInfo");
         Field field2 = field.get(view).getClass().getDeclaredField("mVisibleInsets");
         Rect rect = field2.get(field1.get(view));

         rect.top = 0;
      }
   }
```

I would rather not have someone suggest XML layout, my application has to be very dynamic and response to various rules as to how to create a layout.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class AndroidLayoutManager {

   private final Activity activity;
   private final Rectangle bounds;
   private final String name;

   public AndroidLayoutManager(Activity activity, Rectangle bounds, String name) {
      this.activity = activity;
      this.bounds = bounds;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public ViewGroup createLayout(ViewLayout viewLayout, ViewComponent headerView, ViewComponent mainView, ViewComponent footerView) {
      AbsoluteLayout relativeLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(activity);
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams fullScreenParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(bounds.width, bounds.height, 0, 0);

      if(viewLayout.isHeaderIncluded()) {
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams headerViewParams = headerView.getLayoutParams();
         View view = headerView.getView();

         view.setLayoutParams(headerViewParams);
         relativeLayout.addView(view, headerViewParams);
      }
      if(viewLayout.isMainIncluded()) {
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams mainViewParams = mainView.getLayoutParams();
         View view = mainView.getView();
         View scrollView = createScrollView(view);

         scrollView.setLayoutParams(mainViewParams);
         relativeLayout.addView(scrollView, mainViewParams);
      }
      if(viewLayout.isFooterIncluded()) {
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams footerViewParams = footerView.getLayoutParams();
         View view = footerView.getView();

         view.setLayoutParams(footerViewParams);
         relativeLayout.addView(view, footerViewParams);
      }
      relativeLayout.requestLayout();
      activity.setContentView(relativeLayout, fullScreenParams);
      mainView.getView().requestFocus();
      activity.getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();

      return relativeLayout;
   }

   private View createScrollView(View view) {
      ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(activity);  

      // ******** WTF??? This is causing a strange layout problem *******
      //scrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      scrollView.requestFocus();
      scrollView.setFocusable(true);
      scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
      scrollView.addView(view);
      scrollView.setFillViewport(true);

      return scrollView;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }

   public static class ViewLayout {

      private Rectangle header;
      private Rectangle main;
      private Rectangle footer;

      public ViewLayout(Rectangle header, Rectangle main, Rectangle footer) {
         this.header = header;
         this.main = main;
         this.footer = footer;
      }

      public boolean isMainIncluded() {
         return main != null;
      }

      public boolean isFooterIncluded() {
         return footer != null;
      }

      public boolean isHeaderIncluded() {
         return header != null;
      }

      public Point getHeaderPoint() {
         return new Point(0, 0);
      }

      public Point getMainPoint() {
         if(header != null) {
            return new Point(0, header.height);
         }
         return new Point(0, 0);
      }

      public Point getFooterPoint() {
         if(header == null) {
            return new Point(0, main.height);
         }
         return new Point(0, main.height + header.height);
      }

      public int getHeight() {
         int totalHeight = main.height;

         if(header != null) {
            totalHeight += header.height;
         }
         if(footer != null) {
            totalHeight += footer.height;
         }
         return totalHeight;
      }
   }

   public static class ViewComponent {

      private final Rectangle rectangle;
      private final Point origin;
      private final View view;

      public ViewComponent(View view, Rectangle rectangle, Point origin) {
         this.view = view;
         this.rectangle = rectangle;
         this.origin = origin;
      }

      public AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
         return new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(rectangle.width, rectangle.height, origin.x, origin.y);
      }

      public View getView() {
         return view;
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your XML?

Comment: Yea we need the layout XML to really see what the issue is.

Comment: I have added my example code, as you can see this is likely a bug in android-2.1_r1 and possibly other versions.

Answer (score 0):

your code `requestWindowFeature(...)` and `getWindow().setFlag(....)` must be BEFORE setContentView(). this is my notification

Comment: Yes, its the very first thing I do, I do the following.          requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);